# Education history in DS160

Tags: b1-b2-visas

My parents are part of a group from India of people above 50 years who are travelling for the purpose of a religious ceremony to the USA. They have obtained an invitation letter from the temple.
Now, they all have provided only their latest graduation details in DS160? Is it compulsory to give high school, senior school etc details also? 
Will this create issues at the interview? Group appointment has already been scheduled and confirmed.